# Force image aspect ratio also on mobile with CSS (object fit:cover not working)

Tags: css

**Background:**

I have a circle thumbnail img (.x-card-img) that crops also rectangular images on desktop.

**Problem:**

However, on lower screen resolutions the thumbnail (right image below) shape morphs into an egg. The problem seems to be that the underlying picture is not square, but that's exactly the problem I want to resolve, so that regardless of what the user uploads, it's always neatly integrated.

**Attempts:**

The widespread solution is to have object-fit: cover and either set height: auto or play around otherwise with width / height and max-width / max-height. I feel like I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

1. **UPDATE 1** As per answer below I added the following to replace the border radius:

   > clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);

   However, this still results in the image being too long and cut off
   the sides. Perhaps a better solution would be to have an attribute
   that zooms the image to fill enough to have a circle?

   [image]
2. **UPDATE 2**

   The second (and accepted) solution below works!! Thanks a lot

---

**Desktop**

[image]

**Mobile**

[image]

**Original image 1**

[image]

**Original Image 2**

[image]

```css
.x-card-box {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 9px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 0px 15px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 1.5625rem !important;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: initial;
    transition-property: initial;
    max-width: 275px !important;
}    
.x-card-name {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #646464;
    padding-top: 30px;

}

.x-card-img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 125px !important;
    max-height: 125px !important;
    margin-top: 15px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container x-card-box">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="x-card-featured col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
  
</div>
  <div class="x-card-name col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
     
<span class="job_listing-title">Betti</span>
                            
  </div>

  <div class="x-card-photo col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        
                    
<img class="x-card-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEW8l.png" alt="Betti">
                    
            
                
            </div>
  <div class="x-card-rating col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        
            
<div class="listing-stars">
                        
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>      
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
                        
                    
                </div>
            
   </div>
  <div class="x-card-more col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button class="x-card-btn">&nbsp;</button></div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- ************* NEXT CARD **************** -->


<div class="container x-card-box">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="x-card-featured col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
  
</div>

<div class="x-card-name col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
     
<span class="job_listing-title">Betti</span>
                            
  </div>

  <div class="x-card-photo col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        
                    
<img class="x-card-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y667l.jpg" alt="Betti">
                    
            
                
            </div>
  <div class="x-card-rating col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        
            
<div class="listing-stars">
                    
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>      
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
<span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
                    
                </div>
            
   </div>
  <div class="x-card-more col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button class="x-card-btn">&nbsp;</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a CSS trick you can use to create an element which preserves any aspect ratios after resizing. The trick exploits the fact that padding percentage value is relative always to the parent element's width (even padding-top/bottom).

**Here's how it works:**

1. Create a parent container (`.x-card-photo` in your case) and give it a `position: relative;` and a desired width (`max-width: 125px;`).
2. Add a pseudo-element for this container (`.x-card-photo::after`) and set its' `padding-bottom: 100%;`. Thus, padding bottom will adjust to the changes of its' parent (set by `max-width: 125px;`). Whenever the parent `width` shrinks, the `padding-bottom` will shrink too!
3. Put anything you like within `.x-card-photo`, give it `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;` so that it fills the entire available space.

**And your code:**

```css
.x-card-box {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 0px 15px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 1.5625rem !important;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: initial;
  transition-property: initial;
  max-width: 275px !important;
}
 
.x-card-photo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 125px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.x-card-photo::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;  /* Edge Fix */
  padding-bottom: min(125px, 100%);
}

.x-card-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**EDIT: further explanation:**

The parent's CSS only specifies its' own `width` but not `height` which is 0 by default. The pseudo element, which sits inside the parent, has no `width`, but it indirectly specifies its' own `height` by means of `padding-bottom: 100%` - which is equal to the parent's `width` due to CSS inner-workings (weirdly enough, if you specify `padding` in percentage value, it will be relative to parent's `width`). Thus, the parent's `height` is now stretched to accommodate space for its' pseudo element's `padding-bottom`. Then, if you place anything inside the parent, let's say an `<img>`, and specify its' own `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` it will fill all available space. Note: the pseudo element has `position: absolute` which places it "on top" of the parent (which has `position: relative`).

**Also note:** the `padding-bottom: 100%` on the pseudo element preserves 1:1 aspect ratio, but you could calculate other ratios, e.g. `50%` is 2:1, `150%` is 1:2, `56.25%` is 16:9, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I tried this, but the image is still longer than a normal circle + it cut off the sides. Would you have any other idea?

Comment: @AlphaX Sure, I updated my answer and let me know if it works!

Comment: Really great this seems to work almost! Only thing is that the image seems stretched to fill the sides and looks distorted. Is there a way to rather force a zoom to fill it into the circle as opposed to stretching it to the sides? I have added another screenshot in the top section. If you look at the desktop image, the picture seems to also get zoomed in to fill the circle. Would be extremely helpful if you could post an alternative solution, without deleting this one!

Comment: @AlphaX The effect you described above and in **UPDATE 2** might be caused by a lack of support for the `object-fit` property. What mobile browser do you use (vendor & version)?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I double checked on the object-fit and realized it was somehow missing, not sure why as I copied the CSS class. Anyway, it works now perfectly on mobile but creates a whitespace from the 100% padding on desktop! Is there an easy fix or would it be best to to just play around with the media queries? Have added a screenshot under UPDATE 2.

Comment: I have played around a bit with it and found out that there is a min function in CSS for padding, so I replaced padding-bottom: 100% with padding-bottom: min(125px, 100%), this way it takes the smaller of both and doesn't add the big whitespace. Will edit in your solution. Update: have edited but it will need to be approved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and fast responses, really appreciate it!!! If you have another second, it would be great if you could explain your pretty smart solution a bit further. I'm not sure how the pseudo element impacts the img. I would have expected the padding would need to be added to the parent div container, so its confusing to me that it can be done via the pseudo, which I would have expected stands by its own without impacting following children of the parent.

Comment: @AlphaX You're welcome! I also added some more info to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the crux was to understand that you can generally set padding to x% to make it equal the parent's width, crazy! Thanks you so much, this has been most helpful, really!

Comment: Hi @83C10 I checked browser compatibility today with IE and noticed that the solution isn't working in IE Edge. It basically shows the div collapsed. Via the inspector I found out that if you set a fixed height to the x-card-photo div (parent of img) it shows up. So I think the issue is that neither the img nor the parent has a determined height. However, if you set a fixed height, then this isn't responsive anymore and the image deformed again. I'm very sorry to come back, but given you were very helpful on this before, would you have any idea how to resolve this for IE?

Comment: @AlphaX It looks like Edge does not understand the `min()` function in `padding-bottom` within `.x-card-photo::after` definition. I edited my answer above where I doubled the `padding-bottom` definition to fix layout in Edge. Look for `/* Edge Fix */` line :)

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, perfect - thanks a lot! The next problem was then again the white space that is created by setting padding-bottom at 100%, however after thinking about it further, that padding bottom is determined by the width, ie just set a max-width to 125px and it now works well. Thanks a lot again - really appreciate it!!